# Tracking mechanism for Gmail: IMAP and POP3 messages in Java(API)

Tags: synchronization, gmail, jakarta-mail, google-oauth

I am developing an Java application and I want to sync Gmail mails. What I want exactly is to develop track-mechanism for emails through my app. Suppose If in my application I have read messages till current time and suppose its(newest) message ID is msg123. After few time, if in my inbox new messages are arrived. I want to read only those newly arrived mails. Like if new messages have ID msg124, msg125 and msg126. I want to read only those messages that have messages ID - msg124, msg125 and msg126.

So my questions are:

**1.** If I am connected to Gmail using POP3/IMAP server using credentials is it possible to query only those emails that are newer than last read mail time-stamp ?

**2.** In my search I found this link which states that with OAuth we can achieve mail tracking(As what I want). Docs ref link [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). Please suggest me if I am in wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth has nothing to do with this problem, and the Gmail API won't make this any easier.

You really need to learn about IMAP UIDs, exposed in JavaMail through the [UIDFolder interface](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html), which IMAP folders implement.

If you keep track of the last UID you processed, you can query for UIDs larger than that using the [UIDFolder.getMessagesByUID method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessagesByUID-long-long-).

Comment: Thanks for your reply the way you suggested worked for IMAP. But still I am stuck at POP3 part.

Comment: If you're only using Gmail, you **really** want to use IMAP, not POP3.  POP3 supports UIDs, but they're different than IMAP, so UIDFolder isn't supported.  POP3 UIDs are unsorted strings.  You need to keep track of all the UIDs you've ever seen, then ask for all the UIDs for all messages in the Inbox to figure out which messages you haven't seen.  You'll need to use the [com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Folder.html) APIs.

Comment: **@Bill Shannon** Using docs ref to pre-fetch all UIDs for all messages:
`FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
fp.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp);`

and `public Message[] getMessages() `
"docs says, Folder implementations are expected to provide light-weight Message objects."

Obtained message objects {`getMessages()`} contains other details like content etc. If that is the case then can you please suggest exact way to retrieve only UIDs.

Comment: The code you have is correct.  The Message objects are just a facade for the data on the server.  When you call getContent (for example), that's when it will issue the IMAP command to fetch the data from the server.